# Use Excel File in C# Microsoft botframework SDK

Tags: c#, excel, botframework, bots

How can I read local excel data on my C# bot using bot framework SDK. I can't find any documentation for it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add more details. Is the bot part of Telegram / Facebook / Other?

Comment: I Firstly want to try in web API later integrate with other channels like messenger WhatsApp or teams

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Bot Framework-specific package for such a thing. However, you are working in C#, so you can simply apply a C# solution to the problem. A basic web search turned up something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302235/how-to-read-from-xlsx-excel), however it would be up to you to choose an appropriate solution.