# How to import excel file from angular to asp.core, than read data and push it in List

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have found package like NPOI, but i dont know how to stream file, or how to convert it to bit before sending to asp.core. Curently i am using Angular 6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197093/5576498please see this link:

Comment: Can you provide more information about how far you are, include any code that you currently have? The more detailed you are and the more specific the question, the better responses you will receive. Also, you have a multi part issue here, best to take it one part at a time, first write the code necessary to upload the file to the web server, then you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Do NOT use Angular/JavaScript to read and parse the Excel file and then send to your web service; these libraries are extremely slow for a file of any significant size.  Instead, use Angular/JavaScript to do a multipart upload to your web service and reconstruct the Excel file in the backend using something like OpenXML.

Comment: I've used code below for Angular part, and IFormFile on the back, and everything seems to be good, but i do not know how to read file, the link in top 
comment work with asp MVC, not with asp.net core 2+. I need help how to read it and  push to IENumerable<dynamic>. I had searched on google, and on stack, but didnt found any good answer, Thank you @programmerj for advice,

Comment: see https://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-excel-asp-net-core-2-razor-pages/ and check whether it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some old code that might help.  Note that the first method was added because I found it was quicker to send the data from Angular to the controller, process, and then send back as opposed to processing the data in JavaScript.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an uploaded Excel file (multipart) to a JSON object. Useful for converting large Excel files instead
    /// of doing so in the browser, due to performance issues with SheetJS JavaScript library.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ConvertedFile")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success", typeof(List<Dictionary<string, object>>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetConvertedFile()
    {            
        var fileData = await processUploadFile();

        fileData = removeEmptyRows(fileData);

        return Ok(fileData);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an uploaded Excel file (multipart) to a JSON object. Sends the file to be processed.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    [Authorize]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success")]
    public Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadExcelFile()
    {            
        var uploadFileData = await processUploadFile();

        // Do something with uploadFileData...

        return Ok();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the upload file by converting uploaded Excel file (XLSX) to "JSON" object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="HttpResponseException"></exception>
    private async Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> processUploadFile()
    {
        var documentData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        try
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            // Manage the multipart file in memory, not on the file system
            MultipartMemoryStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

            // Should have only one "content" or file.
            HttpContent content = streamProvider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();

            // Convert the HttpContent to a Stream
            using (Stream fileUploadStream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                // Convert the Excel file stream to a List of "rows"
                documentData = ExcelManager.ExcelDataReader(fileUploadStream);

                if (documentData != null)
                {
                    // header rows are not represented in the Values.
                    Log.Information("Order Data - Processed {0} lines of file data", documentData.Count);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Warning("File processing error. No data.");
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Log.Debug("Excel File took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, string.Format("Test File Processing error."));
            throw;
        }

        return documentData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the empty rows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="documentData">
    /// Represent a list of excel rows. Each list item represent a row. Each Dictionary key represent the column
    /// name. Dictionary value represent cell value.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<Dictionary<string, object>> removeEmptyRows(List<Dictionary<string, object>> documentData)
    {
        // build a new collection that only contains rows that have at least one column with a value
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> nonEmptyRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        if (documentData != null && documentData.Count > 0)
        {
            // evaluate each item in the list
            foreach (var item in documentData)
            {
                bool isRowEmpty = false;

                // evaluate each Key/Value pair.
                // RowID, State, and Message are the fields added to the document for state tracking.
                // Do not consider those fields.
                foreach (var key in item.Keys)
                {
                    if (key != "RowID" && key != "State" && key != "Message")
                    {
                        var value = item[key];

                        Type type = value.GetType();

                        isRowEmpty = type.Name == "DBNull";
                    }

                    // if an non-null value is found within the current row then stop processing this item and
                    // continue on to the next item (excel row).
                    if (!isRowEmpty)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // if the row has user supplied data then include it 
                if (!isRowEmpty)
                {
                    nonEmptyRows.Add(item);
                }
            }

            Log.Information("Removed {0} empty rows from excel File", documentData.Count - nonEmptyRows.Count);
        }

        return nonEmptyRows;
    }


using Excel;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
public static class ExcelManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Read the steam file to convert it into a list of dictionaries
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileUploadStream">The file stream</param>
    /// <param name="columnNames">The column names to be read in the excel file</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> ExcelDataReader(Stream fileUploadStream)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> docData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;

        try
        {
            excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileUploadStream);

            // Columns names are not handled
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

            bool isEmpty = isFileEmpty(excelReader);

            if (!isEmpty)
            {
                // note: files that have only the header row will throw an exception when AsDataSet is called.
                DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        data[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
                    }
                    //This filter duplicates inserts with the same OrderLinkId
                    if ((docData.Exists(e => e.Values.ElementAt(0).Equals(data.Values.ElementAt(0)) && e.Values.ElementAt(1).Equals(data.Values.ElementAt(1))) == false))
                    {
                        docData.Add(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            excelReader.Close();
        }

        return docData;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies the file has at least one row of data. No header fields are used in the file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="excelReader">The excel reader.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool isFileEmpty(IExcelDataReader excelReader)
    {
        try
        {
            while (excelReader.Read())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // swallow this exception.
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use form data

HTML

```html
<input  accept=".xlsx,.csv" (change)="uploadFile($event)" type="file" #file />
```

TS

```
uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (this.validateFile(file)) {
      this.isUploadInprogress = true;
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('files', file, file.name);

      this.uploadService
        .uploadFile(formData)
        .subscribe(
          uploadResponse => this.uploadSuccess(uploadResponse, file),
          error => (this.isUploadInprogress = false)
        );
    } else {
      this.invitationsService.showError('Please upload valid file');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but I have done it on that way on front, but i didnt knew how to read it on back, i'd watched many tutorials that showed  us how to work with it while file is on server, with fileStream and parh in it, but noone with I IFormFile variable, so i tought it could be better idea to send binary data from Angular.

Comment: Thank you very much! i will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

html: (Angular ->primeNg)

Ts:

```
onFileUpload(event) {
const file = event.files[0];
this.progressBar = true;
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
this.Service.importexcel(formData).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

}

asp api core controler: You can separete it in arhitecture after with await... And than send it to SQL from ienumerable after checking regex.

```
    [HttpPost("import", Name = "ImportExcel")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImportExcel([FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
        string folderName = "Upload";
        string newPath = Path.Combine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +'_'+ folderName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }            
            string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
            ISheet sheet;
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
            var list = new List<ShipmentImportExcel>();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            if (sFileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read the Excel 97-2000 formats  
                sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook  
            }
            else
            {
                XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read 2007 Excel format  
                sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook   
            }
            IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0); //Get Header Row
            int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;


            for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++) //Read Excel File
            {
                var obj = new ExcelObject..();
                IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);

                obj.property1 = row.GetCell(0).ToString();
                obj.property2 = row.GetCell(1).ToString();                   

                list.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        return Ok(list);

    }
```