# Using IFormFile in Asp Core

Tags: asp.net-core

i'm usin asp core 2.2

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create")]
    public IActionResult Create([FromForm]SubjectWebFullDto newWeb)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(new BadRequestError("Incorrect Model"));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newWeb.SourceWeb))
                return NotFound(new NotFoundError("Incorrect Model"));

            var subject = _subjectService.Get(newWeb.SubjectId);
            var newObj = newWeb.LoadFrom(subject.Guid);
            _subjectWebService.Insert(newObj);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

every thing without upload image on local and server are fine.
when upload image in local reponse OK:
[Local Api Post Man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKlmT.png)

but in server iis failed:
[Server Api Post Man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tin.png)

i'm using server iis 7
what's problem of uploading image in server?

Model:

```
public class SubjectWebFullDto
{

    public int WebId { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required]
    public string SourceWeb { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300)]
    [Required]
    public string Lead { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Descript { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you push code of SubjectWebFullDto

Comment: It seems your model is not valid on production version. For further investigation please show us necessary parts of your model and view.

Comment: please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658913/uploading-and-reading-from-an-excel-file-in-asp-net-core-2/56197093#56197093

Comment: It seems my model is not valid but Where?????exactly when "newWeb.image" Get filled error 400 has return!