# Read excel file using .NET core in aws lambda

Tags: c#, excel, lambda, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app running in AWS Lambda. I now have a requirement to read and do some calculations on an Excel file. I've found two libraries for Excel parsing in .NET Core, but each doesn't seem to be able to run in lambda for different reasons:

- https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core: Requires libgdiplus to be installed
- https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI: Requires .NET Core 2.0

Do I have any options besides:

1. Wait for lambda to support .NET Core 2.0
2. Not use lambda

Thanks.

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436525/how-to-parse-excel-rows-back-to-types-using-epplus/37746915#37746915

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking at an alternative option, you can use Google Sheets and API instead of using Excel.

The Google Sheets API can be invoked from Lamda and if there are complex reads and writes, you can also write an App Script in Google Sheet and invoke it also from Lambda.

We were in a similar situation and imported the Excel to Google Sheets and was able to make the calculation work.

Comment: As a followup, we've been using the Google Sheets API for a while now, and its working really well. The API is better than any of the .NET/Excel alternatives IMO.